# .htaccess RegEx for variable file version

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like clients to be able to access certain files using an arbitrary version number to bypass caching.

For example, suppose there are two files: styles.css and jquery.min.js They should be able to request either the originals or styles.23.css and jquery.min.5039.css.

The rule I came up with was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(?!\..*)[\d]+\.(.*)$ $1.$2 # strip out version number
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Broken down, here's my thought on what it should be doing:

```
^(.*) – starting from the beginning, match all
\. – up to the first period...
(?!\..*) - ...which is not followed by a period and anything,
[\d]+\. – then match if ends in one or more digits followed by a period...
(.*)$ – ...and anything
```

This RegEx actually works seems to work in PHP but not .htaccess, which has me a bit confused.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need lookahead etc. Following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.\d+\.(.*)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I had completely forgotten about putting an additional "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" before the rule when testing various patterns, so they all failed at one point or another. I ended up using a variation of yours except instead of (.+?) at the beginning (which removes the first set of digits), I used (.*) which effectively removes the last, so file.12.34.123456.js loads file.12.34.js.